# Connecting to ZNC over SSL

Tags: emacs, irc

I try to setup ERC > ZNC connection over SSL. The no-SSL connections works fine. The problem is when I try to connect using [Erc](https://www.gnu.org/software/erc/) via `erc-tls` command, nothing happens, the "Opening Connection.." message stays forever.

ZNC config:

```
AnonIPLimit = 10
ConnectDelay = 5
ProtectWebSessions = true
ServerThrottle = 30
Skin = _default_
StatusPrefix = *
SSLCiphers = EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocols = -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
Version = 1.7.2

<Listener l>
    IPv4 = true
    IPv6 = false
    SSL = true
    AllowIRC = true
    AllowWeb = false
</Listener>
...
```

Emacs config:

```lisp
  (setq tls-program
    '("gnutls-cli --x509cafile %t -p %p %h"
      "gnutls-cli --x509cafile %t -p %p %h --protocols ssl3"
      "gnutls-cli --priority secure256 -p %p %h"))
```

I connect via ERC: `(erc-tls :server "server.domain" :port 55555 :nick "znc-nick" :password "znc-nick/freenode:znc-password")`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was caused by too strict network profile in Emacs, which disallowed incoming self signed certificates. To work around this, and keep the current settings intact I created function which I run to start ERC session. I use [ZNC](https://github.com/sshirokov/ZNC.el) package to connect with ZNC server.

```lisp
  (defun my/znc-all ()
    "Connect to all ZNC networks. Accept incoming self signed certificates."
    (interactive)
    (let ((tls-checktrust nil)
           (gnutls-verify-error nil))
      (znc-all)))
```